# Split string and also get delimiter in array

Tags: regex, groovy

I want to split a string like this:

```
"Street:§§§§__inboundRow['Adress']['Street']__§§§§ und Postal: §§§§__inboundRow['Adress']['Postal']__§§§§ super"
```

My code in Groovy:

```
def parts = ret.split(/§§§§__inboundRow.+?__§§§§/)
```

So the array what I get is

```
["Street:", " und Postal: ", " super"]
```

But what I want is:

```
["Street:", "§§§§__inboundRow['Adress']['Street']__§§§§", " und Postal: ", "§§§§__inboundRow['Adress']['Postal']__§§§§", " super"]
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with `javascript`?

Comment: This code is from groovy, grails

Comment: why `String1` not have `:` in the end and `andString2:` do? or it is a typo?

Comment: It is a type, its just pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting on a positive lookahead.  Since you want to retain the delimiters you use to split, a lookaround is probably the way to go here.

```js
var str = "String1:§§§§__inboundRow[Test]__§§§§andString2:§§§§__inboundRow[Test1]__§§§§";
console.log(str.split(/(?=§§§§__inboundRow\[Test\d*\]__§§§§|and)/));
```

I don't know what exact language you are using, but this should work anywhere you may split using regex, with lookahead (JavaScript certainly supports it).  The pattern use to split was:

```
(?=§§§§__inboundRow\[Test\d*\]__§§§§|and)
```

This says to split when we can assert that what follows is either the text `§§§§__inboundRow[Test\d*]__§§§§` or `and`.